# I'm looking for a very specific kind of iPhone 4S case

Tags: iphone, case

I can't seem to find a good case with the following traits:

1. As protective as possible while simultaneously fulfilling the rest of the criteria on this list (size is not an issue)
2. Doesn't muffle your voice
3. Doesn't interfere with the camera in any way
4. Doesn't interfere with the controls in any way
5. Doesn't require you to remove the case from your phone to charge it or use other accessories
6. Good for gaming

Comment: Screen protectors get the bubbles during application if you're not very careful. I doubt there's much difference between the models.

Comment: @CajunLuke I'm talking about built-in screen protectors. Not regular screen protectors. The kind that are frequently attached to the front of more heavy duty cases get air bubbles in them once you start using the touch screen through it. Namely the Ballistic HC and OtterBox Defender. Although according to a gentleman who gave an answer on my question here his Griffin Defender does not suffer from this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided on the LifeProof case. It fulfills all of the criteria provided in my question. All of your ports are covered, it's versatile, and comfortable to hold in your hands for long periods of time even while gaming. Not to mention the possibilities for using it around water. I highly recommend it to anyone seeking a similar case.

Comment: but it's very expensive..

Answer (score 1):

Here is the one I use:

[Griffin Survivor](http://www.griffintechnology.com/armored)

Ok, it's fat and ugly.

But it protect screen, and all the device without interfering with sound quality and others functionalities.

The screen protector dont cause any bubble problem.

You don't have to remove the case to charge if you use Apple cable. Some cables made by other manufacturer don't fit perfectly.

The front camera work fine, and the back is protected by a piece of amovible rubber.

It's very well designed, IMHO.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question I've already looked at the Griffin Survivor and I do indeed like it. I don't think it's ugly at all. I'm worried about the built-in screen protector causing air bubbles between it and the screen. Does this happen?

Comment: Not at all! The screen protector is perfect.